# react native shadow props costume (android)

Tags: android, react-native

why react native does not allow us to shadow costumes on our components that only provide one option (Eleveation) for Android, this makes the UI on Android a little stiff

Answer (score 0):

The processing shadow in react native is platform-specific. In android, the implementation of custom shadow is not easy one.

Since Android OS 21(Lollipop), the `elevation` option is only a way to showing shadow in general scope. But in iOS, the customizing shadow is easy. with `UILayer` options.

Also, Google recommend just use `elevation` for implementing material design UI/UX. In Material design guidelines, the elevation values indicate shadow levels.

In Android, if you want to show custom shadow for your views, then you have to use render script API or other rendering process that are considered hard.

If you want use custom shadow, you can use [react-native-shadow](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow#readme).

Comment: shortcomings of react native, can not own shadow costumes on Android, without having to use a library (unlike react native competitors) who can shadow costumes

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can customize shadow on android with `React Native Androw`.

Here is the link: https://github.com/folofse/androw/tree/master/react-native-androw

I've been using this for a while (even on alive production apps) it is working perfectly :) also, its author is really helpful tho.